Can I use points for instances to inform my textures?
Specifically, because the instances clip into the surface(craters instanced onto the ground), I was hoping I could put a transparent dot right there to allow the clipping issue to not show up in renders. I have tried the "floaters" approach, but I want to add more than craters, so that would cause issues for the other objects. I would still use the floaters effect on the craters, but only for the very edges of the instances.

Here is the the issue, the crater is as flush with the ground as possible, making the inside of the crater clip. You can see bits of the other craters, they are other instances on a seperate mesh.


Here is my floaters approach, however the perspective I use makes this approach non ideal.

nodes for the floaters gimmick

